# Is it okay to say “Your explanation really solved my concerns"

Tags: expressions, american-english

Is it okay to say “You explanation really solved my concerns"? What are other ways to express this? Thank you!

Comment: Your *concern/s* is/are more likely to be ***resolved*** (or maybe ***allayed*** in some contexts).

Comment: There are better ways to phrase it, but your sentence has valid syntax and is clear and meaningful.  Nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 5):

"Solve" implies a more black-and-white context—a *problem* is either solved, or not—whereas a *concern* admits of intermediate responses or responses of indeterminate magnitude—it may be "addressed" (giving no information as to the success of the response), or "ameliorated" (indicating a reduction of concern). To connote a fully successful response, you might say “Your explanation really *allayed* my concerns."

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that you no longer have that concern, perhaps you could say that.

You may also try:

[Dispel](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispel)

> to make (something, such as a belief, feeling, or idea) go away or end.

There's also a [related SE post by @FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/107361/50044)  explaining why *allay* is the better option here as in *allay someone's concerns*

Comment: I was reminded in reviewing that thread that "alleviated" and "assuaged" also occupy positions along the continuum of possibilities. (What is it with "concerns" and verbs beginning with "A?")

Answer (score 0):

I'd say  "your explanation really addressed my concerns"